# file upload inside update panel loses the file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a update panel in a page and Whenever a value is selected from the dropdown box I display some text on the page, I have set triggers for the drop down, even after doing it the page does a post back when i change the drop down value, where am i going wrong

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP_DDL" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <ContentTemplate>
          <asp:FileUpload ID="File_Audio" runat="server"  />
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_SendAt" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl2_SelectedIndexChanged">
           <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Now</asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem>After 1 Hour</asp:ListItem>
             </ContentTemplate>
      <Triggers>
          <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddl_SendAt" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />                                
      </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I want the DropDownList to make a postback to display contents in text box, but I have a file upload button as well. When I select a file from computer and change the dropdown list a post back happens and the file upload loses the file

Comment: is the file upload control inside the updatepanel or outside?

Comment: it is inside the update panel

Answer (score 3):

I would bascially not recommend a FileUpload control inside an UpdatePanel. A file upload normally needs a full postback.

Except if you implement your file upload inside a frame.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `ScriptManager`'s `EnablePartialRendering` property is not set to `False`, and remove it or set it to `True`